# Finding a term inside a <title> bracket in html

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a specific string that contains a keyword inside a title tag in html e.g.

```
<title>Bla bla bla String bla bla</title>
```

I am unsure how to construct that beyond the starting:

```
\<title\>(Word Keyword)\<\/title\>
```

I also want to make sure if I use any wildcards regex may be able to use that the wildcard between the keyword and the  doesn't inadvertently go all the way to the end of perhaps another title block in the html.

Lastly I'm trying to find a way to then

- extract the Word Keyword only even though I've capture the entire regex
- extract/keep the  separately.

This is because I'll have several types of  to captiure from and I want to extract both the 'Word Keyword' and the tag name it came from. Is this possible? I've looked into named groups but not sure if/how to extract after e.g.

```
(?P<TAG>(\<title\>|\<head\>)(?P<TERM>(Word Keyword))\<\/title\>
```

Naturally with any wildcard code as needed to make the above work but assuming it does I'd then want to be able to extract, after matching the string:

- title
- Bla Keyword

or

- head
- Yada Keyword

Comment: don't use regex to parse HTML...

Comment: I guess using XPath would be much easier... `//title`

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Hi in fact we parse/clean the html in the main step and simply look for string patterns to identify text. However one of the many pattersn that would identify the text we are looking for it <title>. So I'm not counting on every html page to look/be the same at all and in fact am using regex to parse. In this case I am backing up a step to use the original html as another way of gathering the desired text string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<(title|head).*?>(.*?)<\/\1>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[This regex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/-0mgtwDVU35AwYGK) would contain the tag in it's first match group, and the inner html of the tag in it's second group - but consider going with XPath or any HTML/XML parser, because of [Zalgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

You need PCRE to use this expression, because of the [non-greedy](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_16.htm) wildcards.